# Apache Tomcat and Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, tomcat

We have Ruby Rails and Apache tomcat servers running on the samw windows server. When the App on Apache Tomcat is installed alone its working fine, but when the ruby app is installed, the Apace Tomcat App stops working. We need to have both the apps running on the same server. Please help. The application running on Tomcat is displaying the login screens and allowing the users the login. And then rest of the things are failing. The application running on Ruby is just fine as expected. Also, we installed Apace Tomcat and then Ruby on to this server. so there are a lot of chances that the Ruby took Tomcat's port. But how to figure out the overlap?

Comment: You might have better luck on serverfault. This is likely a port configuration error.

Comment: What are you using for a ruby server? Are you trying to run them both on the same port?

Answer (score 3):

You probably have both trying to bind to port 80. Whatever server you're using for rails (passenger via nginx/apache http server, nginx+thin/mongrel, etc) is bound to port 80, then tomcat tries to do the same and can't.

If you're using nginx, I would configure tomcat to run on 8080 and reverse proxy http requests to tomcat based on the hostname of part of the url.

You can do this too with apache http server with mod_proxy.

Comment: Thanks Jack. The application running on Tomcat is displaying the login screens and allowing the users the login. And then rest of the things are failing. The application running on Ruby is just fine as expected. Also, we installed Apace Tomcat and then Ruby on to this server. so there are a lot of chances that the Ruby took Tomcat's port. But how to figure out the overlap?

Comment: First of all, what ruby server are you using? Mongrel, thin, unicorn, passenger, webrick?